# Using Intellij IDEA Ultimate for static web site development

Tags: java, tomcat, web, intellij-idea, web-development-server

I'm trying to use `Intellij IDEA Ultimate` for developing static (no dynamic pages - plain HTML + javascript) web site. Currently I'm using `Tomcat` as a local server and `tomcat` plugin for `IDEA`. Actually, the site later will have RESTful layer, which will be deployed to `google-app-engine`, but currently I'd like to fully focus on the client-side.

I have the following project directory structure:

```
--+ src
  |--+ main     
  |  |--+ webapp
  |  |  |--+ js
  |  |  |--+ css
  |  |  |--+ html
  |  |  |--- index.html
```

My main requirement for such development - is to immediately see the changes I make in html/js/css without the need for rebuilding the project. For this purpose believe I need to configure somehow the run configuration for `tomcat` being looking directly into `webapp` directory (and not exploded war directory). Is there such way? I'm fully open for other options for local server rather than `Tomcat`, which might be simpler for this purpose and which can run in `Windows`

Comment: FYI, IntelliJ 2020.1 has a new built-in HTML Preview feature. As you make changes to HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files, the preview automatically renders the page immediately. See "Built-in HTML Preview" section of [*IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1 EAP 1: Support for Java 16, WSL 2 Support, Run Targets, and More*](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2021/01/intellij-idea-2021-1-eap-1/), a JetBrains blog post 2020-01-27.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put your content in a directory somewhere under your project and point a browser at the index page on the filesystem. Every time you change something in Idea, refresh the page -- it'll work. You don't need a server at all for any of that

Comment: I've updated the question - actually the project has the `RESTful` layer as a backend. Currently it has no real logic - only stubs, but I need to be able to serve requests for javascript part of the web site

Comment: The answer still stands though. Just point your browser at the filesystem and you'll get the live update you want. You don't need anything else to make this work. Your javascript can still call onto your rest functions at https://localhost:8080/api (or whatever) to hit the rest services.

Comment: Actually I need them to use relative URL, in order to be able work both locally and deployed. So in this case it will try to look for REST at `file:///...`

Answer (score 1):

## `CATALINA_BASE`

Catalina is the part of Tomcat that provides web server ability.

By default, Catalina looks to Tomcat's own "webapps" folder for the content of the web sites it serves. You can easily override that default. You can specify a "Tomcat base" setting where you specify a particular folder. Search for `CATALINA_BASE` to learn more.

Answer (score -1):

You're currently using an [application server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_server) where it sounds like you just need a [web server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server).

You can easily set up a basic web server that will serve up your HTML and JavaScript files. A great option, if you have Python installed, is [SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html#module-SimpleHTTPServer).

Comment: It would be really good option if my RESTful backend (see my updated question) was python based. But I need it to be java based, and I need the javascript client-side be able to communicate with the RESTful api

Comment: The fact that SimpleHTTPServer runs on Python is irrelevant to the backend - you don't have to write or use any Python code, it's just a Python application.

If your backend is Java running on Google App Engine, that's what's important. The web server simply lets you run the code in the browser (and the JavaScript in the browser communicates with the backend).

Comment: But they cannot listen on the same port at the same time. One of them is needed to serve static HTML and another in order to process incoming requests, but  both should be available at the same port (in order to keep the same root URL)